# Why does a user get logged out (or their token invalidated) whenever a new build is deployed to Cloud Run?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-run

I currently have an application running on Cloud Run. The application also uses Firebase auth.
I've also setup CICD via Github actions.

Whenever there's a new redeploy, it seems like the current logged-in user gets logged out (or the user access token is invalidated). I say this because I've created a python endpoint that validates the user access token via the firebase sdk.

Could this be the case? If so, what are some ways to mitigate this issue?

Comment: Have you tried [`firebase auth with JWT`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#reserved_custom_token_names) which generates custom tokens to identify users

Comment: The user you are referring to is a web UI user? Does it get the token directly from Firebase or mediated by your service? Looks like you have some kind of state going lost when the service goes down.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I was originally going to go with creating custom tokens, but I'm opting to use auth.getIdToken on requests. It seems like this will take care of updating the token if it's expired (within 5 min) https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken

let me know if you guys have comments / advice